# Linux NFS mount on Solaris: Operation not supported on transport endpoint

Tags: linux, solaris, nfs, acl

Filesystem exported from Linux box, mounted on a Solaris box.  On the Solaris box, certain operations fail on this filesystem.  In particular:

```
$ touch z1; install --mode 0444 z1 z2
install: setting permissions for `z2': Operation not supported on transport endpoint
```

The "install" program here is from GNU coreutils version 6.12

This used to work when the server side was a Network Appliance.

The "chmod" works to set the permissions, but "install" does not.  I ran "truss" to see what exactly was failing and it shows this:

```
facl(4, SETACL, 4, 0x0004A938)                  Err#122 EOPNOTSUPP
```

Running truss on chmod indicates it is using a different system call:

```
chmod("z2", 0444)                               = 0
```

The server is running RHEL 6.4 on x86_64.  It is exporting the filesystem using the options:

```
rw,async
```

The client is running Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.1) on sparc (sun4u).  It is mounting the filesystem with these options:

```
remote/read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/vers=3/xattr/dev=5d414f4
```

The "vers=3" was added as an attempt to fix this problem, but it did not.

Given that this used to work fine when the filesystem was being served by the Network Appliance, I'm guessing it has something to do with how the server side is configured.

My guess may be unfounded though.  I've found two other ext4 filesystems mounted from the same server to the same client that don't exhibit this behavior.  But the mount options in those cases are:

```
remote/read/write/nosetuid/nodevices/rstchown/intr/hard/noquota/xattr/dev=5d41520
```

and

```
remote/read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/intr/hard/noquota/xattr/dev=5d41521
```

The common items are "intr/hard/noquota".  Any idea why these might make a difference?

---

**Answer**: Turns out that @roaima was on the right track.  I thought the underlying filesystems were all ext4, but for some reason some of them (the working ones) were xfs.  When we transferred the problematic filesystems to xfs and then shared via NFS to the Solaris box, things worked as expected.

Comment: What's the filesystem underpinning the NFS export? Is it mounted to support ACLs?

Comment: Are you running as root on the Solaris client?

Comment: Linux does not support ACLs, that may be the reason.

Comment: @schily I just searched through all the other filesystems shared from the server to the client and found one that did not exhibit this behavior.  The mount options in this case are: `remote/read/write/nosetuid/nodevices/rstchown/intr/hard/noquota/xattr/dev=5d41520`

Comment: You did not mention what kind of install program that is and why/how it tries to set the ACLs. Linux does not supprt ACLs with NFSv3 and it may be that it fakes empty ACLs with NFSv4, since Linux does not support NFSv4 ACLs.

Comment: @schily GNU coreutils install version 6.12.  I will update the question with this information.

Comment: GNU tools are in general not known for working ACL support. It looks like the program just likes to clear inherited ACLS and is not prepared for the errno that you get from the incomplete NFS implementation from the Linux NFS server. In other words, you should make a bug report against that install program.